# Angular 8 - Cannot read property 'focus' of null when accessing an element in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following html (modal-login.component.html):

```
<input placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-input" #loginFormPassword />
```

This is my code from the ts file (modal-login.component.ts):

```
ngOnInit() {
    for (const key of Object.keys(this.loginForm.controls)) {
        if (this.loginForm.controls[key].invalid) {
            // here key value is "password"
            const invalidControl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('[formcontrolname="' + key + '"]');
            invalidControl.focus(); //Here it gives me the error in console
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying the following, but not working ok, I am not getting an error, but the input password does not capture the focus:

```
  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement);
    this.el.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

But I am getting the following error in the browser console:

```
core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null
```

What could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: Use afterViewInit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that view elements are not defined until the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook is called by angular.

```
@ViewChild('my-el', { static: false })
public el: ElementRef<any> | undefined;

public ngOnInit(): void {
   console.log(this.el); // always undefined
}
```

---

```
    @ViewChild('my-el', { static: false })
    public el: ElementRef<any> | undefined;

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
       // If an element was found by @ViewChild(), it will be defined here
       // it could stil be undefined if no element was found.
       console.log(this.el);
    }
```

Comment: @ViewChild() in Angular 8 required two elements, how would it be then?

Comment: like this:  @ViewChild("loginFormPassword", {static: false}) Component

Comment: @Eladerezador Yes you're right, thank you :) nothing changes though

Comment: In ngAfterViewInit() print console.log(this.el.nativeElement); and I see: <input class="form-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" ng-reflect-klass="form-input" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="password">

Comment: But when I execute this instruction for the focus, visually it still doesn't catch it, maybe this is not the instruction: this.el.nativeElement.focus();

Comment: There may be some actions that prevent it from focusing or losing focus right after, you can try to use `setTimeout` to focus the element slightly delayed. `setTimout(() => this.el.nativeElement.focus(), 1);` If you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` you may also need to manually tell angular to refresh the view, using `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`

Comment: [Heres a stackblitz for reference](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ftflr7?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanksss, working ok, with the setTimeout, also I can to declare a ViewChild in one line: @ViewChild('loginFormPassword', {static: false}) fieldPassword: ElementRef;